# Question migration information is mangled when post is moved from site to site (to site)

Tags: bug, status-deferred, migration

It seems that questions which are migrated from [site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/php-server-that-can-be-run-without-an-installer-from-usb?noredirect=1) to [site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/php-server-that-can-be-run-without-an-installer-from-usb) to [site](https://serverfault.com/questions/213840/php-server-that-can-be-run-without-an-installer-from-usb) get a little weird in the intermediate steps. As you can see from the links, a question was originally posted on Web Applications, where it was deemed off-topic and migrated to Webmasters. Below the question, there is a notification with a link showing this migration event.

On Webmasters, there is a notification with a link showing that the post was migrated from Web Applications, which is expected. However, there's two things wrong here. First, the question was migrated from Web Applications 13 hours ago, but the notification says it was only 9. Second, the post was then migrated from Webmasters to Server Fault **twice**, and there's no notification of either of these migrations on Webmasters outside of the [revision history](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/6834/revisions).

[image: Post on Webmasters]

You can now find the final migrations of the post both [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/213766/php-server-that-can-be-run-without-an-installer-from-usb) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/213840/php-server-that-can-be-run-without-an-installer-from-usb), and the notification that the post was migrated *from* Web Applications (seen above) seems to get its time from the second migration of the post *to* Server Fault.

Ideally, it shouldn't be possible to migrate the same question from the same site twice. Also, there should be a notification on Webmasters that links to one of the migrated posts on Server Fault, since if you were to click on this question on either Web Applications or Webmasters, you wouldn't be able to follow it to Server Fault where it actually got answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support multi-migration at this point.

Any question I see that gets migrated more than 1 place, I will delete from every site it is on.

Additionally, the type of questions that are so broad and badly asked that nobody can figure out where they need to go -- are usually bad questions and should be deleted anyway.

Comment: Works for me. I'd like to think this scenario doesn't come up very much in the first place.

Comment: Multi-migration may not mean people can't figure out where it belongs, but that the only way to get a question migrated from Site A to Site B is to go through Site C.

Comment: @rebecca moderators can do arbitrary migrations. Again: if I see multi-migration, all posts get deleted.

Comment: Mods can migrate to an arbitrary site?

Comment: Bump. What's all this about arbitrary migrations? (Or could you pop into the lounge for a few minutes?)

Comment: Do you mean developers? If that's the case we could do with a "flag for developer attention" option to bring these to someone's attention.

Comment: -1 for the 3rd statement. Perhaps the migrations occur to quickly. before it is clear whether to go from SO to SF or SU. When Database Administrators is up, we will have more confusion of this kind.