# Is this question migrated to Server Fault closed intentionally?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, migration

For a migrated question I see in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533924/unable-to-install-oracle-closed) and in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/216275/unable-to-install-oracle)

The question in Server Fault is closed too, but I miss the entries who and why it is closed.

Is there a bug in the migration process?

Comment: Something similar in this question too - http://superuser.com/questions/13991/macbook-battery-cycle-count

Comment: @Sathya - that one is now at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/macbook-battery-cycle-count

Comment: I WILL FIX THIS! SOMEHOW!

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon: Glad to hear, but which answer am I going to choose? The only answer doesn't quite match.

Comment: @bernd_k: Jarrod will probably answer it after he fixes the bug. If not, someone else will, or else I'll edit my answer. Don't worry about choosing an answer yet.

Comment: @Michael Myers OK for now I choose your answer, as the thing got planned

Comment: Accept rate means almost nothing on Meta, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: No its more moving out of active questions. Its on someones agenda, but for the rest of us it isn't hot anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/226074/unable-to-install-oracle) after the stop in Server Fault (I found this out by [hacking the URL to see the revisions list](https://serverfault.com/posts/216275/revisions)).

Jeff [has said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72647/question-migration-information-is-mangled-when-post-is-moved-from-site-to-site/72658#72658) that multiple migrations are not supported, so this bug will probably not be fixed.

Comment: Here's your link ♪ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72647/question-migration-information-is-managled-when-post-is-moved-from-site-to-site/72658#72658

Comment: @Grace Note: Thanks. I *thought* that was the one, but even knowing that I commented on it, I still couldn't find it. Probably because I got sidetracked with another question about migrating to Programmers.SE.

Comment: With the sudden explosion of sites it might be time to revisit Jeff's decision. It might not be worth fixing for a question or two, but if it's becoming more and more common...

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer possible to "multiple migrate", that is, send a question from

1. Stack Overflow
2. Server Fault
3. Super User

We **disallow migration of already migrated questions** so you can only migrate a question *once*.

(Diamond mods can still manually multiple-migrate but it is frowned upon.)